# Does a heroic trigger still resolve if the heroic creature is gone?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Having read [When does Heroic trigger?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18175/when-does-heroic-trigger) I think the answer is yes, but I'd just like to double check:

I have [Akroan Crusader](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAkroan%20Crusader%5d) and I cast [Nyxborn Rollicker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNyxborn%20Rollicker%5d) for its bestow cost so my stack looks like (LIFO):

- heroic trigger (token creature)
- Rollicker

My opponent then casts [Disperse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDisperse%5d) on my crusader:

- Disperse targeting crusader
- heroic trigger (token creature)
- Rollicker

That's the final play, so after the stack resolves the creatures I should have are a 1/1 red soldier with haste (token) and a Nyxborn Rollicker. Is that correct?

Comment: Abilities on the stack exist independently of their source. If information about its source is required and the source no longer exists, use last known information (LKI).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Abilities still resolve if the creature that created them is gone*, or cards like [Torch Fiend](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Torch%20Fiend) would be a little bit useless. This is because of the following rule:

> 112.7a Once activated or triggered, an ability exists on the stack independently of its source. Destruction or removal of the source after that time won’t affect the ability. [...]

So in this case: your Akroan Crusader gets targeted by a spell, and puts a triggered ability on the stack. Even if the Crusader goes away, the ability still resolves. Then your Nyxborn Rollicker enters the battlefield as a creature instead, since its target is gone.

<sup>* Other stuff can make it fail to resolve, such as if the ability has targets and all its targets are now illegal - see [rule 608.2b](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Resolving_Spells_and_Abilities). But *the originating creature dying* won't do anything to prevent the ability from resolving.</sup>

Comment: Good point about the Torch Fiend. I hadn't thought about it that way.

Comment: You might want to add that the ability still resolves **if it still has legal targets**. If it targets the creature it came from, for example, it would not resolve.

Comment: @murgatroid99 added, sound ok?

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: I was like "Why should the Rollicker resolve? It will surely fizzle". Then I read up on the Bestow ability and was surprised that it actually works the way you describe. +1