# Can I play two instants back to back?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Basically lets say I attack with [Triton Shorestalker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Triton%20Shorestalker). My opponent can't block. Can I then play [Become Immense](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Become%20Immense) and [Titanic Growth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Titanic%20Growth)?

Or if I attack with a creature that can be blocked and my opponent chooses not to can I then play Become Immense and Titanic Growth?

Comment: Related: [instants and priority](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/12652/409); the top answer there quotes from the basic rulebook.

Comment: Tangentially, it is better *strategy* to play one, see if your opponent does anything, then play the other.

Comment: Oh ya of course I guess I was curious cause I thought u had to respond to something in order to play an instant but thanks attack play titanic growth wait then play become immense

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. There's no limit to the number of instants you can cast, other than having the mana available to pay for them. Is there anything in particular that made you think such a limit would exist? If you haven't done so, check out the [basic rule book](http://www.wizards.com/magic/rules/en_magic_basic_rulebook_20090710.pdf).

For your second question, yes, at the end of the "declare blockers step", in which your opponent will have decided whether or not to block, each player then gets a chance to cast instants or activate abilities.

From the basic rulebook:

> An instant is just like a sorcery, except you can cast it just about any time you want,
> even during your opponent’s turn or in response to another spell. Like a sorcery, an
> instant has its effect, then you put it into your graveyard.

And

> Your opponent decides which, if any, of his or her
> untapped creatures will block your attacking creatures,
> then they do so. If multiple creatures block a single
> attacker, you order the blockers to show which is first
> in line for damage, which is second, and so on. Players
> can then cast instants and activate abilities.

Note that there are 2 ways to cast 2 instants during the same step:

1. You can cast the instants one at a time, waiting to cast the second until after the first resolves. Most commonly this is smarter, because you can see what your opponent does before deciding to cast the second one.
   Or:
2. You can cast the second instant immediately after casting the first, in which case the second one you cast will resolve first. If you wish to do this, then you must state as you cast the first instant that you wish to retain priority, otherwise you are assumed to be passing it after casting the instant. You would need to do this if, for example, you wanted to cast [Fork](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fork), targeting your first instant.

Comment: No nothing in particular just wanted to make sure what I am doing is legal but thank you you deff helped alot.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that in a tournament, the only way to stack instants is to explicitly state that you are holding priority.

Comment: That's only if you care about having the second one resolve before the first one. Otherwise, you can just cast the second one after the first one resolves.

Comment: @Gendolkari There's more to it than that. Say you attack with Triton Shorestalker. Then, you cast Become Immense and Titanic Growth without holding priority. Your opponent responds with Bile Blight. Because you are assumed to have passed priority between each spell, you are assumed to have never even cast Titanic Growth. Titanic Growth will return to your hand. It is important to know this so that you don't get bullied into being three-for-oned at a tournament. It happens more often with abilities that you can activate multiple times (e.g., "Pump my guy six times?").

Comment: Wouldn't "I cast Become Immense then Titanic Growth" be a valid understood shortcut for "I cast Become Immense retaining priority, then I cast Titanic Growth"?

Comment: @Rainbolt And even if not, my point is that you don't need to cast both before your opponent responds. It would be smarter usually to cast Become Immense, then wait for your opponent to pass priority allowing Become Immense to resolve, THEN cast Titanic Growth.

Comment: @Gendolkari No, it is not a valid shortcut. The word "explicit" means exactly what you think it means. You're right - it would be smarter to cast and resolve these two specific spells sequentially. My point is that is exactly what happens by default. Also, what about the cases where it isn't smarter? For example, [Humble Defector](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=391856) and [Refocus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=391904).

Comment: @Rainbolt - I believe that such an example is outside the scope of this question. The OP wanted to know if he could cast more than one instant during the same step; he was not interested in the difference between casting a second before the first resolves and casting the second after the first resolves.

Comment: @Gendolkari Fair enough. It is outside the scope of the very specific example used in the question.

Comment: @Rainbolt I added a brief paragraph about it anyway.

Comment: @GendoIkari, No, "I cast Become Immense then Titanic Growth" doesn't clearly mean what you suggested. In fact, to me, it means the opposite. It tells me you mean to cast Titanic Growth after Become Immense resolves (similar to when you say "I activate it 4 times"). That would require that you pass priority after casting Titanic Growth.