# Selfless Spirit Vs Unsummon

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My opponent plays [Wrath of God](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWrath%20of%20God%5d). In response I use [Chord of Calling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChord%20of%20Calling%5d) to get [Selfless Spirit](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSelfless%20Spirit%5d), so I can sacrifice Selfless Spirit and have all of my creatures become indestructible. Then my opponent responds to that action with [Unsummon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUnsummon%5d).

Would the Selfless Spirit's ability still resolves before the Wrath of God (and would it be sacrificed) - or - will Selfless return to my hand (and its ability will not resolve)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Wrath of God" -VS- "Chord of Calling" + "Selfless Spirit" sacrificed in response](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/33958/wrath-of-god-vs-chord-of-calling-selfless-spirit-sacrificed-in-respons)

Comment: @tsuma534 It's not quite a duplicate - this question is building upon the previous one and asking whether a different effect would prevent Selfless Spirit's ability. It may have a relevant answer already in another question.

Comment: @tsuma534 looks like a duplicate on first look, but this new question arised as new gamming actions occurred. Previous one laid on the stack subject, this one laid on the sacrifice action.

Comment: Seems like it's not a duplicate because Unsummon is an instant. With Wrath of God, there's only one order possible: Wrath, then Chord, then sacrifice Selfless Spirit. With Unsummon, depending on priority, you could have Chord, Spirit (and no Unsummon), or Chord, Unsummon, Spirit.

Comment: Well, the question has an answer there, and the answer is: The stack.

Answer (score 6):

Costs are paid when the ability is put on the stack.  Sacrificing Selfless Spirit happens as soon as you put the ability on the stack. The selfless spirit is no longer there to be the target of unsummon, even though the ability is still on the stack.

Comment: As a consequence of this, the opponent had no chance to cast the Unsummon at all (at least not targeting Selfless Spirit). I'd say that might be worth mentioning.

Comment: Well, they *could* cast it if it's their turn. The active player (the player whose turn it is) gets priority after a spell or ability resolves, so when Chord of Calling resolves, if it's the opponent's turn, they'll get priority and could cast Unsummon. It's mostly pointless, because the OP could then sacrifice Selfless Spirit in response, but I suppose they might do it if they wanted to force the decision about whether to sacrifice it.

Comment: I suppose that the same would happen if a lightning bolt for example would be casted in response to the sacrifice action. So, sacrificing a creature would instanteanously remove it of the battlefield. Thank you for all the answers! You have been very helpfull :)