# Stopping a CounterSpell with Aurelia's Fury it's possible?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

**I know you can stop a** [Counterspell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCounterspell%5d) **with another** [Counterspell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCounterspell%5d)

---

But [Aurelia's Fury](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAurelia%27s%5d%2b%5bFury%5d) is different, it causes the damaged player to be unable to cast non-creature spells this turn.

Lets say for example if I cast any spell and my opponent uses a [Counterspell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCounterspell%5d), effectively countering my spell but in response (when he passes priority back to me) I use [Aurelia's Fury](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAurelia%27s%5d%2b%5bFury%5d) and manage to deal damage to him. I passed priority back to him but he has nothing else in response so the stack resolves.

So the stack would look something like this:
Aurelia's Fury
Counterspell
My Spell

As Aurelia's Fury resolves, does this mean his counterspell counts like it was never cast? Meaning my spell was never countered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, your spell hasn't been countered yet because Counterspell hasn't resolved yet. The most recently cast spell on the stack resolves first.

Secondly, countering a spell doesn't retroactively prevent it from being cast. It simply moves it from the stack to its owner's graveyard, which prevents it from resolving.

Thirdly, while Counterspell hasn't resolved yet, it has already been cast.

> 601.2. To cast a spell is to take it from where it is (usually the hand), put it on the stack, and pay its costs, so that it will eventually resolve and have its effect. [...]

To respond to a spell means to cast a spell or activate an ability after a spell has been cast but before it resolves.

[Aurelia's Fury](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAurelia%27s%5d%2b%5bFury%5d) prevents a player from casting noncreature spells. It has no effect on spells, especially those that have already been cast (e.g. the [Counterspell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCounterspell%5d) on the stack).

Instead of casting Aurelia's Fury, say you had cast [Counterspell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCounterspell%5d) targeting the earlier Counterspell. This would have worked because the newest spell on the stack (i.e. your Counterspell) resolves first (i.e. before your opponent's Counterspell), countering the opponent's Counterspell (preventing it from resolving and having an effect).

Instead of casting Aurelia's Fury, say you had cast [Autumn's Veil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAutumn%27s%5d%2b%5bVeil%5d). Autumn's Veil prevents spells from being countered. This would have worked because the newest spell on the stack (i.e. Autumn's Veil) resolves first (i.e. before the Counterspell), preventing the Counterspell from affecting your spell.

Comment: Mm I see. What if I cast Aurelia's Fury at the beginning of my turn? Can my opponent still cast a non-creature spell after that? Sorry very noob at this it would seems obvious but mtg have so many rulings...

Comment: They could cast a spell in response to AF. But once it resolves, they can't cast any more spells until the end of your turn.

Comment: Interesting. That means if my opponent casts Forfend (Prevent all damage that would be dealt to creatures this turn), I could cast In response a lightning bolt dealing 3 damage to target creature. Both spells will resolve? It can only prevent any damage dealt after the first two spells correct?

Comment: LB in response to Forfend results in a damaged creature. Forfend in response to LB results in an undamaged creature. Last one cast is first to resolve. /// In both cases, both spells resolve. Spells are countered 1) by spells and abilities that instruct you to counter a spell, and 2) by a rule which comes into play when all of a spell/ability's targets are invalid when the spell/ability would resolve.

Comment: I'm really confused now. You said they could cast a spell in response to my Aurelia's fury like a counterspell. They will both resolves but if counterspell resolves that means Aurelia's fury was countered effectively and didn't took place. But if Aurelia's fury resolves as well he couldn't have cast counterspell.

Comment: Stop saying "didn't took place". That's wrong. Countering a spell doesn't undo its casting; it removes it from the stack (preventing it from resolving).

Comment: Counterspell in response to AF targeting AF would prevent AF from resolving. /// AF in response to Counterspell has no effect on Counterspell. AF doesn't counter spells.

Comment: @Chris I think this other question may help you: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12652/in-plain-english-how-does-casting-spells-and-using-creature-abilities-work-with