# Narset, Parter of Veils interaction with Aria of Flame

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

If I have [Narset, Parter of Veils](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNarset%2c%20Parter%20of%20Veils%5d) on the battlefield on one loyalty counter and my opponent has an [Aria of Flame](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAria%20of%20Flame%5d) on the battlefield, what happens if the opponent plays [Faithless Looting](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFaithless%20Looting%5d)? I know the opponent can destroy the Narset but can they draw cards with the Faithless Looting I understand it depends on if the trigger from Aria goes on the stack first or second. My guess is that they can draw cards as the trigger from Aria goes on the stack second and thus would resolve first, destroying Narset, then Faithless L resolves, allowing them to draw cards. Is this correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

You have it correct, they will be allowed to draw cards.

The specific order is:

- Opponent casts Faithless Looting... that casting process looks completely normal and doesn't interact with Narset at all.
- Aria of Flame's ability triggers, going on the stack on top of Faithless Looting
- Aria of Flame's ability resolves, dealing damage to Narset
- Narset goes to the graveyard due to having 0 loyalty counters
- Faithless Looting resolves
- Faithless Looting acts completely normally, because Narset is not around.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is correct. By the time Faithless Looting resolves, Narset isn't on the battlefield anymore, so the opponent can draw cards.

(I'm not sure if there is a canonical Q&A for how the stack works, maybe it's time to write one?)

Comment: I think this is the best general question on the stack asked so far:  https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12652/in-plain-english-how-does-casting-spells-and-using-creature-abilities-work-with

Comment: @John I had previously linked to that same question, but then deleted my comment because I realized that it's really asking more about priority and when you can do things; while this question is specifically about the order that things will go on the stack and resolve when you have a "when cast" trigger.